# Will I lose my privileges?

Tags: support

Let's say I have ... 15k reputation. I have the privileges of a **trusted user**. Now, the site goes out of beta. And therefore, the required reputation for being a trusted user is **20k**.

In this case, *will I lose my privileges*? If not, what will happen?

Comment: Are there still unclarities about the existing answers that you might want to adress in a comment?

Answer (score 10):

When a site graduates from beta, all the users privileges reset to the normal thresholds. In the example you give, yes you would lose 'trusted user'.

Comment: By 'normal levels' you mean 1 Rep?!

Comment: @Siddhartha ..... no your reputation score is unchanged.  If your rep is 15k before, it is 15k after, but you lose the privileges that are above that reputation.  The privileges reset to normal thresholds.

Comment: So basically I have to reach 20k to gain 'trusted user' but all the privileges normally available on a non-beta site for 15k wil stay... right?

Comment: @Siddhartha - yes.

Comment: That's kind of suckitude. :(

Comment: @JohnP I agree, and if I don't continue as moderator it will irk me slightly to lose the 20k privileges. However in my opinion the most important thresholds for a user are 2k (edits) and 3k (close/reopen voting).  I hate it when I cannot edit a question, but I can live without moderator tools. You are very close to having both sets of privileges here, even when we've graduated.

Comment: @iandotkelly - I'd be closer if people would stop downvoting my actress ID question :p